# How to return a function pointer in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Let's say I want an increment function, which takes in an argument f (which itself is a function), and returns a function g, whose property is that g(x) = f(x) + 1.
In python, the code would be like:

```
def increment(f):
    def g(x):
        return f(x) + 1
    return g
def f(x):
    return 2 * x
print(increment(f)(5))
```

The result would be 2 * 5 + 1 = 11
I want to implement a similar increment function in C. I don't want to use lambdas (I think only  C++ has them). How to proceed?

I know that you can't nest functions in C. I tried using function pointers but the return type of the increment function and its body is confusing to me. Any sources to learn more about function pointers would also be helpful.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++?  The title says C++; the content says you want to code it in C.  Dual-tagging questions with both C and C++ is more apt to earn opprobrium and downvotes than accolades and upvotes.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean C or C++? The title says one, the post another and the tags say both.

Comment: You can't create functions on the fly in standard C.  In many systems (but not necessarily embedded systems), you can dynamically load functions via a shared library, but that's about it.  In extremis, you could run the compiler to create the desired function and a shared library to load, but that's clumsy at best.

Comment: The python example relies on the fact that functions are objects in that language (and that you can create closures). Since C has neither of these traits you cannot do this with function pointers alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that `g` is not really a function pointer in python, but a closure. i.e. it is not only a pointer to a function (`__call__`), but also some data (the function `f` in this case).

You can do the same in C by defining a struct for the closure `g`:

```
typedef struct {
    int (*f)(int);
    // maybe more fields here
} g_t;
```

And then construct this type in the equivalent of the `increment` function:

```
g_t increment(int (*f)(int)) {
    g_t closure;
    closure.f = f;
    // maybe init more fields here
    return closure;
}
```

Finally, C doesn't have member functions, so we implement the call operator of `g_t` as a free function:

```
int g_call(g_t self, int x) {
    return self.f(x) + 1;
}
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
int f(int x) {
    return 2 * x;
}

int main(void) {
    // print(increment(f)(5))
    printf("%d\n", g_call(increment(f), 5)); // 11
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you can't simply have two separate functions, one `g(x)` and one `f(x)` then call them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int x)
{
     return 2*x;
}
int g(int x)
{
     return f(x)+1;
}
int main()
{
     int n = g(10);
     printf("%d\n",n);
     return 0;
}
```

`g(x)` calls `f(x)` and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't has closure/lambda.

So you cannot return `g` as-is.

your function might take function pointer though:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int increment(int (*f)(int), int x)
{
     return f(x)+1;
}

int twice(int x)
{
     return 2 * x;
}

int main()
{
     int n = increment(twice, 5);
     printf("%d\n", n);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest functions in C, and a function cannot produce a function.   But using functions pointer, you can define a function combining function pointer calls.

```
// compute y from x and combination of 3 functions pointers
int  calc_combine( int x, int (*f)(int), int (*g)(int), int (*h)(int) ) {
    return  (*h)( (*g)( (*f)(x) ) );
}

int  increment( int x ) {
    return  x + 1;
}
int  get_double( int x ) {
    return  2 * x;
}
int  square( int x ) {
    return  x * x;
}
int  same( int x ) {
    return  x;
}

int main() {
    printf( "increment(double(square(3)))=%d\n", calc_combine(3,square,get_double,increment) );
    printf( "increment(4)=%d\n", calc_combine(4,same,same,increment) );
    printf( "square(square(2))=%d\n", calc_combine(2,same,square,square) );
}
```